# form_for submit button, style button to be text instead of a button

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I want text instead of the button that is provided in rails.

I've added a class to the submit button, but this is where I'm stuck. Normally in CSS if I want something to be text I just don't style it. But in this case, the button is styled automatically to look like a button.

How do I overide this and make it look like just text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your button with a class of no_style (or whatever you would like):

```
<button class="no_style">test</button>
```

Then in your stylesheet call the button with a class of no_style:

```
button.no_style {
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
```

You may need to inspect the button to see if there is any other styling on it.  You can inspect it by right clicking on the button and select "inspect element". If your button has any other styles, I can help you remove them.  Just let me know if anything else shows up and I can show you how to remove it.

If you want to change the text you can still style the text without the look of a button, like this:

```
button.no_style {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize the button was being styled by backgorund and border. I also didn't realize I could inspect the css element with the developer tools. TY for pointing that out to me it will be very useful in future